# CSS font-family different order

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the same font-family property in two different projects, and here's how firebug shows them.

1)
[Arial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ye84.png)

2)
[Open Sans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXtJh.png)

How come that first one has 'Arial' marked as active (blue), and second one has "Open Sans". I want Open Sans to appear active on both, because in current situation fonts are not the same.

Comment: In first case, fonts is not loading properly bcz of some error. May be you forgot to `link` fonts?

Comment: kindly link the font family

Comment: font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf'); } 
  font-face { font-family: Delicious; font-weight: bold; src: url('Delicious-Bold.otf');} in this way

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't link the Google font on first one

Answer (score 1):

There are two main steps to take when installing Google Fonts.

---

1.Add the link to the fonts file location on Google Servers

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

OR

Add an import link to your css file:

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);`

---

2.Add the css to link the two together with your elements.

`font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;`